# Dropping rows at specific minutes

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I am trying to drop rows at specific minutes ( 05,10, 20 )
I have datetime as an index

```
df5['Year'] = df5.index.year
df5['Month'] = df5.index.month
df5['Day']= df5.index.day
df5['Day_of_Week']= df5.index.day_name()
df5['hour']= df5.index.strftime('%H')
df5['Min']= df5.index.strftime('%M')
df5
```

[image]

Then I run below

```
def clean(df5):
for i in range(len(df5)):
    hour = pd.Timestamp(df5.index[i]).hour
    minute = pd.Timestamp(df5.index[i]).minute
    if df5 = df5[(df5.index.minute ==5) | (df5.index.minute == 10)| (df5.index.minute == 20)]
        df.drop(axis=1, index=i, inplace=True)
```

it returnes invalid syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do it using boolean indexing, assuming that the index is already parsed as datetime.

```
df5 = df5[~((df5.index.minute == 5) | (df5.index.minute == 10) | (df5.index.minute == 20))]
```

Or the opposite of the same answer:

```
df5 = df5[(df5.index.minute != 5) | (df5.index.minute != 10) | (df5.index.minute != 20)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here looping is not necessary, also [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529702/loop-on-pandas-dataframe).

Use [`DatetimeIndex.minute`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.minute.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) and inverted mask by `~` filtering in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df5 = df5[~df5.index.minute.isin([5, 10, 20])]
```

For reuse column `df5['Min']` use strings values:

```
df5 = df5[~df5['Min'].isin(['05', '10', '20'])]
```

All together:

```
def clean(df5):
    return df5[~df5.index.minute.isin([5, 10, 20])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the right synthax to combine a logic `OR` inside an `IF` statement is the following:

```
    today = 'Saturday'
    
    if today=='Sunday' OR today=='Saturday':
        print('Today is off. Rest at home')
```

In your case, you should probably use something like this:

```
if df5 == df5[(df5.index.minute ==5)] OR df5[(df5.index.minute ==10)]
        ......
```

---

***FINAL NOTE:***

You made some mistakes using `==` and `=`

In Python (and many other programming languages), a single equal mark `=` is used to assign a value to a variable, whereas two consecutive equal marks `==` is used to check whether 2 expressions give the same value .

```
= is an assignment operator

== is an equality operator
```